# VALIDATION ERRORS

Tags: actions-on-google

I get an error when I run a code with a transaction update. What should I do?

> MalformedResponse
>   expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0].input_value_data.transaction_decision_value_spec.proposed_order.cart.line_items[0].sub_lines[0].line_items[1].sub_lines[0].sub_lines[0]:
>   line item must not have more than $0 note(s).

when say "confirm transaction" I get response 

`{
  "audioResponse": "//NExAASWo...",
  "conversationToken": "CiZDIzU5Y2...",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "response": "Here's your order summary. Your total is $38.99 . Ready to place the order?",
  "visualResponse": {
    "agentLogoUrl": "",
    "visualElements": []
  }
}`

Can you answer me more?

When I want to get the delivery address I request "Get address"
and i get response "Your Google Account is missing a delivery address. You can add an address, then come back and try again."

`{
  "audioResponse": "//NExAAQyD...",
  "conversationToken": "GhZzaW11bG...",
  "response": "Your Google Account is missing a delivery address. You can add an address, then come back and try again.",
  "visualResponse": {
    "agentLogoUrl": "",
    "visualElements": []
  }
}`

Comment: Can you update the question to include the code that is sending back your response or the JSON that is being sent back, please?

Comment: While the additional information is useful, the problem is with the response that YOU are sending that does the transaction update. We need to either see the code that is sending that transaction update or the JSON that your code is sending back. You can sometimes see this in the "Response" tab in the simulator.